# Make polylines based on routing on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to create a route in google maps involving multiple waypoints, but google's API does not allow more than 23 waypoints into a route. As a solution coded in order to add markers and draw routes between markers using polylines. The code worked perfectly, but stopped at one point generating the route in half, anyone know if this is more a limitation of Google Maps?
source code:

```
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PolylineEncoder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var trafficLayer;
var bikeLayer;
var poly;
var LocationsMarkers = []; 
var Employees =[];
var latlngCenter;

function GetMarkers(){
  for (var i = 0; i < Employees.length; i++) {
    var Employee = Employees[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Employee[1], Employee[2]);

    // Add the location to vector for routing
    LocationsMarkers.push(new google.maps.LatLng(Employee[1], Employee[2]));

    // Add a marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: Employee[0],
        zIndex: Employee[3]
    });
  }

  // If the length of LocationMarkers > 1, i'm get the routes and i create the polyline.
  if (LocationsMarkers.length > 1){

      var polyOptions = {
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3
      }
      poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
      poly.setMap(map);

      for (var a = 0; a < LocationsMarkers.length; a++) {
          calcRoute(LocationsMarkers[a], LocationsMarkers[a+1]);
      }
  }
}

// calculate the route on the markers.
function calcRoute(start, end) {

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
    };
    var path = poly.getPath();        
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.routes.length; i++) {
               for (var i2 = 0; i2 < response.routes[i].legs.length; i2++) { 
                 for (var i3 = 0; i3 < response.routes[i].legs[i2].steps.length; i3++) {              
                   // add the start and end location by the legs of routes on the path to the polyline
                   path.push(response.routes[i].legs[i2].steps[i3].start_location);
                   path.push(response.routes[i].legs[i2].steps[i3].end_location);
                 }
               }
            }
    }
    });
}

function TrafficOn()     { trafficLayer.setMap(map); }
function TrafficOff()    { trafficLayer.setMap(null); }
function BicyclingOn()   { bikeLayer.setMap(map); }
function BicyclingOff()  { bikeLayer.setMap(null);}
function StreetViewOn()  { map.set("streetViewControl", true); }
function StreetViewOff() { map.set("streetViewControl", false); }

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    CollectData();

    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 18,
       center: latlngCenter,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }; 

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    GetMarkers();
}

function CollectData(){
 // In this example I used only 20 markers, but there will be situations where I have  to show more than 50.          
 Employees = [["1",-20.14669,-44.888862 , 1],
            ["2",-20.1454,-44.892467 , 2],
            ["3",-20.14403,-44.890579 , 3],
            ["4",-20.142741,-44.886716 , 4],
            ["5",-20.143668,-44.885922 ,5],
            ["6",-20.14256,-44.885579  ,6],
            ["7",-20.141512,-44.885879 ,7],
            ["8",-20.140465,-44.885997 ,8],
            ["9",-20.138722,-44.88545  ,9],
            ["10",-20.137886,-44.887071,10],
            ["11",-20.137201,-44.891106,11],
            ["12",-20.137483,-44.892157,12],
            ["13",-20.138047,-44.893251,13],
            ["14",-20.138631,-44.894303,14],
            ["15",-20.139296,-44.895311,15],
            ["16",-20.138208,-44.895204,16],
            ["17",-20.136476,-44.895569,17],
            ["18",-20.137765,-44.897049,18],
            ["19",-20.138067,-44.899238,19],
            ["20",-20.138994,-44.900461,20] ];

  latlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(Employees[0][1],Employees[0][2]);
}
</script></head>
   <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

[image: Image of map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the return status of the DirectionsService.  It is returning OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

Note that the [maximum number of waypoints in the Google Maps API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) is 8 (plus origin and destination), unless you pay (Maps API for Business).

If you check the status and retry after a delay if the error is OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, it will eventually finish:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_directions_multipleWayPts.html

Comment: Ok, My intention is to use this way to bypass this limitation, but I see that even the paid API limit me about this. Thanks of your attention.

Comment: The limitation is there for a reason (to prevent abuse of the free service), you shouldn't be able to "bypass" it.  If you add delays to the calls to the DirectionsService to prevent the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors, you can do what you are trying to do, it will just take a longer time to load.

Comment: I understood and my intention is use the paid API, but my question is: 
using the paid API i can work with more than 23 waypoints? if no, I'll probably have to do something similar to what was discussed above.

Comment: I don't know the answer to limitations on the paid API (I don't use it).  Your [Google sales rep (if you can find one)](http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/request.py?&contact_type=gme#utm_campaign=en&utm_medium=et&utm_source=devsite-en-compare) can tell you whether that limitation is negotiable or not.